# Why do divisions like 1/98 and 1/998 give us numbers continuously being multiplied by two each time in decimal form?

Tags: decimal-expansion

For example, when I divided $1$ by $98$, I got an amazing result of $0.0102040816326530612244897...$ where so many numbers get multiplied by two every time in the right pattern with some carrying.  Also, when I divided $1$ by $998$, I got an amazing result of $0.0010020040080160320641282...$.  I have a longer result from my cool memory, which is $0.001002004008016032064128256513026052104208517034068136272545090180360721442885...$What explains why this doubling thing is happening?  I love it when I see it!  Also I don't know if it repeats (I'm talking about 1/998).  I think it does because I looked it up and it said 498 numbers repeat every time, so it's rational.  I mean seriously, how does this doubling happen?  I hope I can receive good information from you!

Comment: $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k,$$ hence $$\frac{1}{10^d - a} = \frac{1}{10^d}\frac{1}{1-\frac{a}{10^d}} = \frac{1}{10^d} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a}{10^d}\right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{10^{(k+1)d}}.$$

Comment: Nice pattern-spotting. Similar $\frac1{97}=0.01030927...$ and $\frac1{997}=0.001003009027081..$ etc. :)

Comment: Also look at $1/997$ and, oddly, $1/9899$

Comment: @Michael - Amazing! A hidden Fibonacci series!

Comment: @DanielFischer Your comment essentially answers OP's question; perhaps it merits being an answer in its own right?

Comment: Interestingly, taking a step back from the OQ, $$\frac18=0.125=0.1+0.02+0.004+0.0008+0.00016_....$$ and from the example above, $$\frac17=0.142857...=0.1+0.03+0.009+0.0027+0.00081+...$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice observation. We can write

$$\frac{1}{98} = \frac{1}{100 - 2} = \frac{1}{100}\frac{1}{1 - \frac{2}{100}}$$

Now for $|x| < 1$, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$

Apply that result to the expression above and we have

$$\frac{1}{98} =  \frac{1}{100}\left( 1 + \left( \frac{2}{100} \right) + \left( \frac{2}{100} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{2}{100} \right)^3 + \cdots \right)$$

That gives the pattern you observe.

You can make a similar analysis for $\displaystyle \frac{1}{998}$.